# CDI Produce Instance Created At Runtime

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

I am new to cdi producer pattern and so far I have seen examples producing simple content already known at initialization point of a class. Now I have to produce an instance created at runtime and filled with some data which also happens at runtime. Here is my current approach but to me it aint that good... Is there a better approach so please help me out with some patterns and practices

```
 public class myBean {
 private DataHolder dataHolder;

  @Produces
  public DataHolder {
   // dataHolder is null until I later init instance 
   return dataHolder;
  }
}
```

At some point in my code I set the dataHolder to new istance and allow futher injections to use runtime data by doing this:

```
dataHolder = new DataHolder(data1, data2, data3);
```

That looks kinda cheep :) is there a better way? or a nice pattern for producing cdi stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is indeed clumsy because if there is an injection of `DataHolder` any time before you initialize it - it will return `null` (if you produce a `@Dependent` object) or even crash (with any other scope).

I suggest you do some reading on Producer methods either in [CDI spec](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#producer_method) or [Weld doc](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html_single/#producer_methods).

Now, my take on this. The cleanest approach would be to let the body of the producer work do all the creation job *every time*. That means either:

1. Adding parameters to producer method **(NOTE: they have to be injectable beans)**
2. Having the parameters necessary to create `DataHolder` in your `MyBean` class ever since it's creation and read them (they have to be available to producer at all times)
3. Put the logic necessary to retrieve these parameters to the producer method

If you stick with returning a `@Dependent` bean, your producer is allowed to return `null` - you can make use of that if you so wish. The injection point can then expect a possible null value which can be interpreted as 'not yet initialized'. Or, if you need different scope (`@ApplicationScoped`, `@RequestScoped`, ...) then it's probably easier to create a second dummy implementation of `DataHolder` which will, again, mean 'not yet implemented'.

**Side note:** Any manually created object (e.g. using `new`) in CDI will **not** have it's injection points resolved automatically. That means, if you inject anything *into* `DataHolder` while creating the `DataHolder` itself using `new`, there will be `null`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. however I would like to know is it possible to have a producer produding an instance which futher produces some other stuff

Comment: I suppose you will `@Vetoed` the class of the instance you produce, therefore then can no longer be a producer on such class (it will not be picked up by CDI). But if you want to produce another bean based on the result of this producer (`DataHolder`) - remember that other producers can inject the produced `DataHolder`, no matter where you place them.

Comment: Lets say I have a master producer producing request scoped instance which futhermore produces another data and that another data shall be allways pulled for master producer as long master producer lives (the request lasts). How to do this?

Comment: CDI will invoke that producer method every time there is a new request and the given request scope bean is required. It will then inject it to *all* the necessary injection points within your app. If there is still something that does not work for you, I probably don't understand what are you trying to say.

Comment: I have asked a new question that explains everything better. Take a look please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43252696/produce-from-master-producer-cdi

Comment: The question is now here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43271652/produce-from-requestscoped-producer-cdi

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to do this:

```
@Produces
@RequestScoped
public Coder getCoder(@New DataHolder dataHolder) 
{
   return dataHolder;      
}
```

another way would be to use what you get as informations for the producer method, such as the InjectionPoint or what else you reach into it.

```
@Produces
@RequestScoped
public Coder getCoder(@New DataHolder dataHolder, InjectionPoint injectionPoint, ClassA a, ClassB b) 
{
   String stringA = a.function();
   dataHolder.someFunction(stringA);
   return dataHolder;      
}
```

I used the last method to create my device with everything I need and need to do nothing else.
Some resources to look at it can be found at
[byteslounge.com](http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/java-ee-cdi-producer-methods-tutorial)
and
[Jboss docs](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.0/en-US/html/producermethods.html)

**EDIT:** The information was quite hard to find for me, but a CDI Producer works in the way that everything you declare as parameter for e.g: getCoder will be injected at call-time. So you can inject services that can help you to collect information at runtime.

Comment: `@New` is deprecated since CDI 1.1 - I strongly advice against it. It was replaced by `@Dependent`.